# Loop through sql server table using values derived from temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to use values derived from a temporary table and use it as where criteria. Please see my code:

```
declare @laneNum int
declare @startDate date = '2019-02-07'
declare @class int = 1
declare @id int 

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempLaneNumber') IS NOT NULL
drop table [#tempLaneNumber]

create table #tempLaneNumber
(
    LANE_NUMBER INT NULL
)


INSERT INTO #tempLaneNumber (LANE_NUMBER)
SELECT DISTINCT EXIT_LANE
FROM [dbo].[TOLL] 
ORDER BY EXIT_LANE ASC

select * from #tempLaneNumber

set @laneNum = (select * from #tempLaneNumber)

begin
    select COUNT(*)
    from [dbo].[TOLL]
    where convert(date, TRXN_DTIME) = @startDate and EXIT_LANE = @laneNum
end
```

If I run up to `select * from #tempLaneNumber` I get this result:

[image]

But if  I use this values as a criteria on a where statement, on the begin statement, I don't get my expected result.

Comment: A variable in SQL Server can only contain a single value so `set @laneNum = (select * from #tempLaneNumber)` will contain one of the values in your temp table. Maybe you want `where EXIT_LANE in (select LANE_NUMBER from #tempLaneNumber)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your query like following.

```
select l.LANE_NUMBER, COUNT(*)
    from [dbo].[TOLL] t
    inner join  #tempLaneNumber l on t.EXIT_LANE = l.LANE_NUMBER
    where convert(date, TRXN_DTIME) = @startDate 
    GROUP BY l.LANE_NUMBER
```

There are multiple issues in your query, i have commented those and modified where ever required.

```
--declare @laneNum int [NOT REQUIRED]
declare @startDate date = '2019-02-07'
declare @class int = 1
declare @id int 

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempLaneNumber') IS NOT NULL
drop table [#tempLaneNumber]

create table #tempLaneNumber
(
    LANE_NUMBER INT NULL
)


INSERT INTO #tempLaneNumber (LANE_NUMBER)
SELECT DISTINCT EXIT_LANE
FROM [dbo].[TOLL] 
--ORDER BY EXIT_LANE ASC [NOT REQUIRED FOR INSERT]

select * from #tempLaneNumber

--set @laneNum = (select * from #tempLaneNumber) [YOU CAN'T ASSING A TABLE OUTPUT TO A INT VARIABLE]

--begin [NOT REQUIRED]
/*
    select COUNT(*)
    from [dbo].[TOLL]
    where convert(date, TRXN_DTIME) = @startDate and EXIT_LANE = @laneNum
*/
--CHANGED
select l.LANE_NUMBER, COUNT(*)
    from [dbo].[TOLL] t
    inner join  #tempLaneNumber l on t.EXIT_LANE = l.LANE_NUMBER
    where convert(date, TRXN_DTIME) = @startDate 
    GROUP BY l.LANE_NUMBER
--end [NOT REQUIRED]
```

Comment: Sir I need to have a count for each LANE_NUMBER. Your suggestion seems to add everything.

Comment: Sir can you answer another   one for me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745094/iterate-through-derived-value-from-temp-table-so-it-value-can-be-used-it-a-where