# Iterate through derived value from temp table so it value can be used it a where condition using for loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can get the total for each of the items from a derived table like so:

```
declare @laneNum int
declare @startDate date = '2019-02-07'
declare @class int = 1
declare @id int 

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempLaneNumber') IS NOT NULL
drop table [#tempLaneNumber]

create table #tempLaneNumber
(
    LANE_NUMBER INT NULL
)    

INSERT INTO #tempLaneNumber (LANE_NUMBER)
  SELECT DISTINCT EXIT_LANE
  FROM [dbo].[TOLL] 
  ORDER BY EXIT_LANE DESC

select l.LANE_NUMBER, COUNT(*)
from [dbo].[TOLL] t
inner join  #tempLaneNumber l on t.EXIT_LANE = l.LANE_NUMBER
where convert(date, TRXN_DTIME) = @startDate 
GROUP BY l.LANE_NUMBER
```

But what I need now is to iterate through each of the derived values so I can use it in a statement where each result can be placed in a variable. This is what I get in my current code...

[image]

I need to put LANE_NUMBER 4 into x4 variable and LANE_NUMBER 6 into x6 variable and so forth. How do I get to it?

**EDIT**

```
declare @laneNum int
declare @startDate date = '2019-02-07'
declare @class int = 1
declare @id int 

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempLaneNumber') IS NOT NULL
drop table [#tempLaneNumber]

create table #tempLaneNumber
(
    LANE_NUMBER INT NULL
)


INSERT INTO #tempLaneNumber (LANE_NUMBER)
SELECT DISTINCT EXIT_LANE
FROM [dbo].[TOLL] 
ORDER BY EXIT_LANE DESC


;WITH CTE AS
(
    select l.LANE_NUMBER, COUNT(*) CT
    from [dbo].[TOLL] t
    inner join  #tempLaneNumber l on t.EXIT_LANE = l.LANE_NUMBER
    where convert(date, TRXN_DTIME) = @startDate 
    GROUP BY l.LANE_NUMBER
)
SELECT * FROM CTE where LANE_NUMBER = 4
```

This is about right but the problem is I would need to hardcode the value "4" or "6" or "7". This sample has 4 results so it's okay. but what if I have 10 or more?

Comment: You'd be better off explaining your end use - because my guess is you could add a column to your temp table to store the value and then query the table as part of your where clause.

Comment: Can I place the current result to another temp table and query it from there?

Comment: Just use the same one - add another column and update it.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. What I need is to put the 1774 into variable x4 and 2007 in variable x6 and so on... I can't figure out how adding a new column can get what I need.

Comment: Because if you add it to the temp table as PSK has shown below you can query as `(select Count_LN from #tempLaneNumber where LANE_NUMBER = 4)` for all lane numbers. Much cleaner than having a variable per lane.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I would be hardcoding the 4 or 6 or 7.. What if I have more than 10?

Comment: You'd be hardcoding it in a variable? Thats why it would help to see your end use to understand how you are using it. We are guessing that you can probably join it on something and not need anything hardcoded.

Comment: In the title you said you wanted to use it in the "where condition of a for loop". Well its very easy to iterate over your temp table, going through each of the lanes and pulling the count to use in a query. Maybe that is your question?

Comment: That's it.. Exactly.. That's why I needed a for loop for that!

Comment: @Ibanez1408 I have updated my answer, you can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the result later on you can use temp table like following.

```
create table #Results
(
    LANE_NUMBER INT NULL,
    [Count_LN] INT
)    

INSERT INTO #Results
select l.LANE_NUMBER, COUNT(*) CT
from [dbo].[TOLL] t
inner join  #tempLaneNumber l on t.EXIT_LANE = l.LANE_NUMBER
where convert(date, TRXN_DTIME) = @startDate 
GROUP BY l.LANE_NUMBER
```

If you want to use the output immediately in the next statement, you can go for CTE like following.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(

select l.LANE_NUMBER, COUNT(*) CT
from [dbo].[TOLL] t
inner join  #tempLaneNumber l on t.EXIT_LANE = l.LANE_NUMBER
where convert(date, TRXN_DTIME) = @startDate 
GROUP BY l.LANE_NUMBER
)
SELECT * FROM CTE --USER YOUR CTE HERE
```

**EDIT:**

I am not able to understand your requirement fully, by any reason if you want to iterate the table and store every row's column value into a variable, you can try like following.

```
create table #Results
(
    LANE_NUMBER INT NULL,
    [Count_LN] INT
)    

INSERT INTO #Results
select l.LANE_NUMBER, COUNT(*) CT
from [dbo].[TOLL] t
inner join  #tempLaneNumber l on t.EXIT_LANE = l.LANE_NUMBER
where convert(date, TRXN_DTIME) = @startDate 
GROUP BY l.LANE_NUMBER



declare @ln int
declare @ct int
While (Select Count(*) From #Results) > 0
Begin
    select top 1 @ln = LANE_NUMBER, @ct = [Count_LN] from #Results
    -- Use the variable @ln and @ct. For example, if you want to call a sp
    -- exec call_someothersp @ln,@ct
    Delete From #Results Where LANE_NUMBER = @ln and [Count_LN]=@ct
End
```